# Issue in taking screeshot of map activity

Tags: android, google-maps, screenshot

I have integrate a map in  my activity now i wanted to take screenshot of map location but its is not taking screenshot properly it is just showing google logo in screenshot 
Here's my xml

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@id/activity_main"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.apple.emergency.MapsActivity" />
 </Relativelayout>
```

and java class code

```
 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements            OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in sudney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
 //   googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new  LatLng(34,15),1));
takeScreenshot();
}
 public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    View rootView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main).getRootView();

    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398602/googlemaps-coded-screenshot-returns-black-image/40398944#40398944

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            mMap.snapshot(new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    // Write image to disk
                 //   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/map.png");
                   // bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                    shareBitmap(bitmap,"my location");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

to share

```
private void shareBitmap (Bitmap bitmap,String fileName) {
    try {
        File file = new File(getBaseContext().getCacheDir(), fileName + ".png");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        file.setReadable(true, false);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(     android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        intent.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```